# Bitmap image causing OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android

i got OutOfMemoryError  when fetching image from url in android.below i mention my code and exception.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bais = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 InputStream is = null; 
URL url = null; 
try { 
url = new URL(image); 
is = url.openStream (); 
byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096]; // Or whatever size you want to read in at a time. 
int n; 
while ( (n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0 )
 {
 bais.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
 } 
is.close(); 
bais.flush(); 
} catch (Exception e) { 
System.err.printf ("Failed while reading bytes from %s: %s", url.toExternalForm(), e.getMessage());
 e.printStackTrace ();
 bais = null; // Perform any other exception handling that's appropriate.
 }
```

> Exception Log: genearted for the above code

```
    03-22 13:04:44.858: E/dalvikvm-heap(1528): Out of memory on a 13131140-byte allocation. 03-22 13:04:44.858: I/dalvikvm(1528):
> "Thread-180" prio=5 tid=25 RUNNABLE 03-22 13:04:44.858:
> I/dalvikvm(1528):|group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0
> obj=0x415deed8self=0x378150 03-22 13:04:44.858: I/dalvikvm(1528): |
> sysTid=1572 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2]handle=1723384 03-22
> 13:04:44.858: I/dalvikvm(1528): | schedstat=( 765401358 258475984 4706
> ) utm=41 stm=35 core=0 03-22 13:04:44.858: I/dalvikvm(1528): at
> java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:~91)
> 03-22 13:04:44.858: I/dalvikvm(1528): at
> java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201)
> 03-22 13:04:44.858: I/dalvikvm(1528): at
> com.lukup.util.FetchImage.run(FetchImage.java:46) 03-22 13:04:44.858:
> W/dalvikvm(1528): threadid=25: thread exiting with uncaught
> exception(group=0x409df1f8) 03-22 13:04:44.868:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1528): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-180 03-22
> 13:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1528): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 03-22
> 13:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1528): at
> java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:91)
> 03-22 13:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1528): at `enter code
> here`java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201)
> 03-22 13:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1528): at
> com.lukup.util.FetchImage.run(FetchImage.java:46)
>   --
```

the above is the exception log

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to make a 13 MB allocation.  Some phones don't let an app use that much memory total, forget about in 1 allocation-  even many new phones would fail that.  Try flushing the output stream more frequently, it may be that its being stupid and keeping the memory around for the entire output until its flushed.